# Print range of columns comma-separated, and the rest without comma-separation

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to figure this out.

```
awk '{print $1","$10","$11","$12","$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19}' <<< "$PASTE_1" > test.csv
```

I need to print the $1 $10 $11 $12 separated by comma then continue with $13 until the of the line, without comma separation. Since there are many blank spaces from $13.

Comment: adding a sample input and output would help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
awk '{a = ""; for (i = 13 ; i <= NF ; i++) a = a $i; 
       print $1 "," $10 "," $11 "," $12 "," a}'
```

The input

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

gives:

```
a,j,k,l,mnopqrstuvwxyz
```

That is, the fields starting from 13 are concatenated together, and then printed after 1, 10, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{print $1, $10, $11, $12, ($13 $14 $15 $16 $17 $18 $19) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print join(",", @F[0,9..11], q//), @F[12..$#F]'
```

### Explanation

1. Array `@F` holds the fields in a line. `@F[...]` refers to a `slice` of elements of array @F. So, `@F[0,9..11]` is the slice consisting of the 1st, 10th to 12 elements of @F which are then `join`-ed together by `comma` and a dummy empty element `q//` is suffixed to the slice to generate the required `,` for the coming `slice`. The other `slice` `@F[12..$#F]` gathers the 13th till the last element of the `@F` array via the `$#F` which holds the last element's idx. (Please note that array indexing is zero-starting in `Perl`).
2. The various arguments to `print` are now joined together with the `OFS` = `$,` (defaults to null).