# Printing columns using AWK?

Tags: awk, cygwin

I have roughly 7 columns on each line, I want to print two specific columns then the remaining columns after the last specified one, example:

```
awk -F: {' print $2 ":" $6 '} a.txt
```

would print columns 2 and 6 from `a.txt`. How would I then go onto print the remaining columns after $6?

So example of input/output would be:

```
    column2:column6:column7:column8:column9...
```

Comment: The `{ }` for an `awk` action/rule should be _inside_ the `' '` (or otherwise quoted). If outside and you have unquoted comma or `..` in the content between them you'll get unwanted brace expansion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print range of columns comma-separated, and the rest without comma-separation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360918/print-range-of-columns-comma-separated-and-the-rest-without-comma-separation)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cut` instead: `echo 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10|cut -d: -f 2,6-`.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want if you have to use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS=":"}{$1=$3=$4=$5="";gsub("^"FS,"",$0);gsub(FS"+",FS,$0)}1' <your file>
```

- The above works by splitting everything into fields via `BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS=":"}`.
- It then clears fields 1,3,4, & 5, by setting them to `""`.
- The 2 `gsub` commands clean things up by removing any colons (`:`) that may start at the beginning. 
  = The 2nd `gsub` removes any sequences of colons (`:`) from the remaining string in `$0`.
- Lastly we print the results via the `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -F: -pale '$"=":"; $_ = "@F[1,5..$#F]"' input-file.txt

 awk -F: '
    {
       a = $2
       for ( i = 6; i <= NF; ++i )
          $(i-5) = $(i)
       NF -= 5
       print a, $0
    }
 ' OFS=":" input-file.txt

 sed -e '
    s/^/:/;s/:/\n/6
    h;s/.*\n//
    x;s/\n.*//
    s/$/:/
    s/^://;s/:/\n/2
    s/^/:/;s/:/\n/2
    s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/
    G;s/\n/:/
  '  input-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to count from the starting index until the last index and concatenate a variable which gets printed at the end:

```bsh
TEST_STRG="column1:column2:column3:column4:column5:column6:column7:column8:column9"
echo $TEST_STRG | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {out=$2; for(i = 6; i <= NF; i++) out = out""FS""$i } END {print out}'
```

- `out=$2`: initializes the variable with the 2nd column
- `i <= NF`: "NF" is the "number of fields" -> the amount of columns resulting by splitting the input
- `out = out""FS""$i`: concatenates the column at the current index to the variable after the field separator "FS"

This will result in the output:
`column2:column6:column7:column8:column9`