# Print only the last three columns from file

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have this file on Linux:

```
 14:00:01.071 5255  604177
4 14:00:01.074 4608  1415742
 14:00:01.074 18398  1122001
2 14:00:01.074 11723  155575
5 14:00:01.075 4695  885808
```

Desired Output:

```
 14:00:01.071 5255  604177
 14:00:01.074 4608  1415742
 14:00:01.074 18398 1122001
 14:00:01.074 11723 155575
 14:00:01.075 4695  885808
```

Command Used:

```
gawk '{ print $NF-1, $NF}' filename
```

But it prints only the last two columns.

Comment: Oh, come on. 1) that script does not print the last 2 columns (you're missing parens around `NF-1`) and 2) assuming you do have a script to print the last column with `NF` and the 2nd-last column with `NF-1`, I struggle to believe you couldn't figure out how to build on that pattern to also print the 3rd-last column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print range of columns comma-separated, and the rest without comma-separation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360918/print-range-of-columns-comma-separated-and-the-rest-without-comma-separation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file1
14:00:01.071 5255 604177
14:00:01.074 4608 1415742
14:00:01.074 18398 1122001
14:00:01.074 11723 155575
14:00:01.075 4695 885808
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming

1. The delimiter is a space
2. You want all but the first column, which may be blank, but will have a delimiter
3. There's only one delimiter between columns

then you can use `cut -d' ' -f2-` to print, from a space-separated values file, the contents from the second column to the last one.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `...| column -t` to have the output properly aligned.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite incorrect, `$NF-1` would print the value of the last column subtracted by one. You need to group the command within `(..)`, since `NF` is a variable

```
gawk 'NF>=3{ print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```

The part `NF>=3` is to safely validate you are printing the last 3 fields on lines that is guaranteed to have at least 3 fields.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -Eo '\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s*$'
```

Which would preserve the spacing in the input. Note that lines that contain fewer than 3 fields are skipped.

POSIXly, the equivalent would be:

```
S='[^[:space:]]\{1,\}' s='[[:space:]]\{1,\}'
sed -n "s/$S$s$S$s${S}[[:space:]]*$/\\
&/;s/.*\n//p"
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested with below command and  it worked fine

```
 sed "s/^[0-9]\{1,\}//g" filename| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"
```

output

```
14:00:01.071 5255  604177
14:00:01.074 4608  1415742
14:00:01.074 18398  1122001
14:00:01.074 11723  155575
14:00:01.075 4695  885808
```

Comment: It should be noted that this command removes digits in the first column as opposed to printing only the last 3 columns. It's thus hard-coded to expect a certain number of columns as input.

Comment: It's also unnecessarily GNU-specific for `-r` and `\s`, using 2 seds and a pipe when 1 could do the same thing, and using double quotes instead of single unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

`awk  '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$(NF)}' file.txt`

Where NF is the number of fields in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged `perl`

```
$ perl -lane 'print "@F[-3..-1]"' ip.txt
14:00:01.071 5255 604177
14:00:01.074 4608 1415742
14:00:01.074 18398 1122001
14:00:01.074 11723 155575
14:00:01.075 4695 885808
```

- `-l` strip newlines from input lines, and add it to end of string when `print` is used
- `-a` autosplit input based on whitespaces, accessible via `@F` array
- `print "@F[-3..-1]"` print the desired fields, the default delimiter when array is specified within double quotes is single space

  - `-1` refers to last field, `-2` refers to second last field, etc
  - `..` is range operator

Use `perl -lane 'print "@F[-3..-1]" if $#F > 2'` if you do not want lines with less than 3 fields to be displayed. `$#F` gives the last index of array, i.e. size of array minus 1